# Creation of interface between C and Pytest in Cython

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, cython, cythonize

1. So I have Cython files [ .pyx and .pxd ], a C file [.c and .h] and a pytest file.

My C file represents a function, a structure, and definitions of structure in .h and .c (for some structure).

So My C file:

- I have abc.h

```
struct Struct1
{

  uint32_t  V_enable_output;
  .. [ some more members which I'm not using]
  ..
}
```

- I have xyz.h

```
#include "abc.h"

void initialize(const volatile struct Struct_1 *config);
```

- I have a test.c

```
struct Struct2
{
 uint64_t V_enable_output_threshold;
.....
.....[some other members not being used]
}

static struct Struct2 state;

static const volatile struct Struct1 *cfg;

void initialize(const volatile struct Struct1 *const config)

{

cfg = config;

state.V_inp = 0u;

state.P_inp = 0ull;

state.P_out = 0ull;

state.V_enable_output_threshold = ((uint64_t) cfg->V_enable_output) << 32u;

}
```

I wanted to write a cython interface for this and test it using pytest:

So my files related to cython goes as follows:

- h123.pxd

```
from libc.stdint cimport *
cdef extern from "abc.h":
    cdef struct Struct1:
         uint32_t V_enable_output
cdef extern from "xyz.h":
    cdef void initialize(Struct1 *config)
```

- C123.pyx

```
cimport h123
from libc.stdint cimport *

cdef struct Struct2:
        uint64_t V_disable_output_threshold

cdef class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def py_initialize(self, config):
        cdef h123.Struct1 config_struct
        config_struct.V_enable_output = config['V_enable_output']
        
        h123.initialize(&config_struct)
```

I wanted to unit-test this function with pytest, the cython files are building and generating .so, so I moved on with pytest:

- test_C123.py

```
import pytest
import pyximport
import sys
sys.path.append('/software/module')

from C123 import Class1

access = Class1()

def test_py_initialize():
    config = {
        'V_enable_output': 2000000
    }

    assert access.py_initialize(config) is None
```

Since the function from C returns nothing so I felt to assert test with 'None' but I get segmentation fault for this.

And I wanted to include the value of 'state.V_enable_output_threshold' in cython files and test the same in pytest, any suggestions on how it would be possible?

I'm able to build cython, but while testing it with pytests, I'm facing segmentation fault, not able to figure out whats wrong.

Comment: You mention you can build it with Cython, but are you able to *run* the function without the pytest framework? A segmentation fault most likely indicates a bug in the C code, not elsewhere.

Comment: Do you get any warnings when compiling? What is your setup/flags for compiling the C part?

Comment: @9769953 I'm not getting any warnings with respect to this function. without pytest framework I'm getting segmentation fault for this particular, while I'm able to test other functions which the C function has some kind of return values. I just feel the way I'm passing and setting the config/config_struct is incorrect.

Comment: "without pytest framework I'm getting segmentation fault for this particular": indeed, so pytest is not relevant here. Perhaps you create a fully standalone, working, example: a [mcve], for others to try out?